# Create uniques object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

My current Data structure is show below which is grouped based on a property called 'submitId'

```
{
   bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d: [
     {...}
   ],
   5ee08c723e1d40b0af716ea3e18c6114: [
     {...}
   ],
   886b149dfe1241efac863d0532b7d847: [
     {...}
   ]
}
```

Actual data based on a single submitId is shown below

```
// ACTUAL DATA
{
   bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d: [
    {
      status: 'FINISHED',
      start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
      end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
      submissionRank: 112,
      submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
      code: 'ATL',
      indicator: 0,
      addBy: 30,
      delayBy: 0,
      pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
      fstat: 'FINISHED',
    },
    {
      status: 'FINISHED',
      start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
      end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
      submissionRank: 112,
      submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
      code: 'AAA',
      indicator: 0,
      addBy: 30,
      delayBy: 0,
      pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
      fstat: 'FINISHED',
    },
    {
      status: 'FINISHED',
      start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
      end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
      submissionRank: 112,
      submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
      code: 'AAA',
      indicator: 1,
      addBy: 30,
      delayBy: 0,
      pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
      fstat: 'FINISHED',
    },
    {
      status: 'FINISHED',
      start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
      end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
      submissionRank: 112,
      submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
      code: 'ATL',
      indicator: 1,
      addBy: 30,
      delayBy: 0,
      pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
      fstat: 'FINISHED',
    },
  ]
}
```

for a given '**submitId**', the unique object is made up of unique combination of 'code', indicator is set as 1 if all objects have 1 and 0 for same reason BUT set to 'both' if a mix of 0 and 1. The uniques object needs to look like below:

```
   {
      status: 'FINISHED',
      start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
      end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
      submissionRank: 112,
      submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
      code: 'ATL, AAA', <--- unique codes
      indicator: 'both', <--- if indicator is even mix of 0 and 1 then 'both'
      addBy: 30,
      delayBy: 0,
      pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
      fstat: 'FINISHED',
    },
```

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and filter to resolve this task:

```js
let obj = {
    uuid: [
      {
        status: "FINISHED",
        start: "2022-05-26 05:01:00.0",
        end: "2022-05-28 05:01:00.0",
        submissionRank: 112,
        submitId: "bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d",
        code: "ATL",
        indicator: 1,
        addBy: 30,
        delayBy: 0,
        pstat: "DATA GATHERED",
        fstat: "FINISHED",
      },
      {
        status: "FINISHED",
        start: "2022-05-26 05:01:00.0",
        end: "2022-05-28 05:01:00.0",
        submissionRank: 112,
        submitId: "bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d",
        code: "AAA",
        indicator: 1,
        addBy: 30,
        delayBy: 0,
        pstat: "DATA GATHERED",
        fstat: "FINISHED",
      },
      {
        status: "FINISHED",
        start: "2022-05-26 05:01:00.0",
        end: "2022-05-28 05:01:00.0",
        submissionRank: 112,
        submitId: "bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d",
        code: "AAA",
        indicator: 1,
        addBy: 30,
        delayBy: 1,
        pstat: "DATA GATHERED",
        fstat: "FINISHED",
      },
      {
        status: "FINISHED",
        start: "2022-05-26 05:01:00.0",
        end: "2022-05-28 05:01:00.0",
        submissionRank: 112,
        submitId: "bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d",
        code: "ATL",
        indicator: 0,
        addBy: 30,
        delayBy: 1,
        pstat: "DATA GATHERED",
        fstat: "FINISHED",
      },
    ],
  };

  let one = false;
  let zero = false;
  let codes = [];
  
  let res = obj.uuid.reduce((t, v, i) => {
    let = indicator = v.indicator;
    let = code = v.code;

    if (indicator === 0) zero = true;
    else if (indicator === 1) one = true;

    if (zero && one) indicator = `both`;
    else indicator = indicator;

    v.indicator = indicator;

    codes.push(v.code);

    unq = codes.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
    v.code = unq.toString();

    return v;
  });
  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `reduce` operation : you want to convert an array of entries into a single entry. The [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is precisely what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is only one set of "real" data to work with I hope that the following shows how you could tackle the task:

```js
const data={
   bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d: [
{
  status: 'FINISHED',
  start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
  end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
  submissionRank: 112,
  submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
  code: 'ATL',
  indicator: 0,
  addBy: 30,
  delayBy: 0,
  pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
  fstat: 'FINISHED',
},
{
  status: 'FINISHED',
  start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
  end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
  submissionRank: 112,
  submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
  code: 'AAA',
  indicator: 0,
  addBy: 30,
  delayBy: 0,
  pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
  fstat: 'FINISHED',
},
{
  status: 'FINISHED',
  start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
  end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
  submissionRank: 112,
  submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
  code: 'AAA',
  indicator: 1,
  addBy: 30,
  delayBy: 0,
  pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
  fstat: 'FINISHED',
},
{
  status: 'FINISHED',
  start: '2022-05-26 05:01:00.0',
  end: '2022-05-28 05:01:00.0',
  submissionRank: 112,
  submitId: 'bc3827d9c21548f8b1ae072ceab4ce6d',
  code: 'ATL',
  indicator: 1,
  addBy: 30,
  delayBy: 0,
  pstat: 'DATA GATHERED',
  fstat: 'FINISHED',
},
  ]
};

const res=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([id,o])=>
 [id,o.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
  if(a.indicator!=c.indicator) a.indicator="both";
  if(i==1)a.code=[a.code];
  else a.code.push(c.code);
  return a;
 })]
));

console.log(res)
```